# Xamarin.Forms - PropertyChanged set {} not called

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I've got a simple **LoginView** and **LoginViewModel**.
First, here is the related code of the View:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Entry
        Text="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    />
    ...
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private string _email;
    public string Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Email)));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If I say inside the Constructor something like

```
Email = "abc";
```

the Entry for sure displays the value "abc". But if I change the Text inside the Entry, the **set {}** is not firing so the **PropertyChanged()** also does not.

Do I miss something here or do I have to use BindableProperties?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit 1

For anyone needing the definition of the BindingContext for **LoginView**, here is the Code-Behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public sealed partial class LoginView
{
    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the ViewModel
        this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

## Edit 2

So I created a Testproject which simply binds the TextProperty of a Entry to a Property. This works! Then I edited my existing Code (removed Baseclasses, simplified everything, etc) to simply do the same basic thing... And it doesn't work. What could this be?

Comment: I went through the docs several times to see if I forgot something, but this code does not differntiate from mine except the BindingContext definition. I do it inside my Views Constructor, the docs do it inside the xaml for the Label itself. But this seems the only difference

Comment: Did you set the `BindingContext`?

Comment: Sure, let me edit my post to show where it is set

Comment: Strange, this bare naked sample seems to work: https://github.com/jfversluis/TwoWayBindingTest

Comment: Hmm, do you think this could be a bug within the Xamarins UWP implementation?

Comment: Does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes it does, as I said, getting the value does work, but setting it when writing something into the entry does not

Comment: Try removing the TwoWay as entry TextProperty is already two ways. Also while your view model seems to implement INotifyPropertyChanged did you actually derive from it (we don't see it)?

Comment: Show us your implementation of OnPropertychanged so well please.

Comment: I didn't implement OnPropertyChanged, there was no need before

Comment: I have similar apps on UWP that use Entry with an explicit TwoWay binding, and it works, so it isn't  completely broken on UWP... Just to clarify what you are seeing: when you type into the Entry box, you are verifying via a debugger breakpoint that the set is not being called, and that _email is not having its value updated.  Correct?

Comment: Correct, and you are right, it also does not work on iOS

Comment: Where I would look next: is there another element in the XAML, like a parent of the Entry, that redefines the BindingContext?  Or is there a LoginView.OnAppearing or other such method that resets BindingContext?

Comment: No there isn't. If there would be, the get {} wouldn't work, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I updated my Xamarin.Forms version, the bug now is gone!